# Php 5/7 error class handling

Tags: php, error-handling

I just recently ugraded to php7 and had my first problem when upgrading some applications using try catch

PHP7 now implements its own error class to handle the errors so the old code that i had:

```
try {
    dispatcher::run(new request);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    require_once APP_PATH . 'error.php';
    $error = new error($e);
}
```

now throws an error because error class is already defined:

```
Cannot declare class error, because the name is already in use in [...]
```

Now this got solved pretty easily just renaming my error class, but it had me wonder, is there a way to extend the error class of 7, and can be both compatible with php5?

Regards...

Comment: None of that code is declaring a class.

Comment: @ceejayoz No but this `$error = new error($e);` attempts to instantiate one

Comment: my custom php5 error class declaration is on the error.php file... i thought it wasn't needed to add the declaration to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short is **you shouldn't do that**, because it's a [backwards incompatible](http://php.net/migration70.incompatible) change.

The long answer is yes, it's possible, but you still **shouldn't do that**, because it can still result in undesired behavior and still might require making changes to your existing PHP 5 implementation.

The `Error` class in PHP 7 implements the same `Throwable` interface that `Exception` implements. The idea was to just have a distinguishing way to identify those exceptions thrown by PHP itself and those thrown by your PHP code. So what you're doing here `$error = new error($e)` is basically the equivalent of `$error = new Exception($e)`, which would be backwards compatible with PHP 5, *assuming your custom `Error` class is compatible with the `Throwable` interface*. Since you didn't provide your class implementation I can't say for sure, but generally speaking, if you hadn't already extended `Exception` in PHP 5, I somehow doubt it will be.

Comment: yes you are right, my error class is not compatible with the throwable interface....

Comment: So then the answer is definitely no.

Comment: I'll look for a tutorial on how to use the throwable clas... thanks for your help!!

Comment: Throwable is not a class. It's an interface. [If you want documentation on something in PHP the best place to look is the manual](http://php.net/throwable).